# Excel VBA + Regular Expression

Tags: regex, vba, excel

Ok, to start. I'm a little rusty on VBA, 3 + years since Ive need to use it.

In short, im struggling to extract text from a string. Im using regular expression to extract my department name and date from this string.

The Department will always fall between : and -.

I can't share the document due to security. But, I can explain the format and hopefully we can work from that.

Col A----Col B----Col C---Col D

Date(e)--Dept(e)--String--Duration

Where (e) means it was extracted from the string.

[image: String Example]

My code for the extraction, thus far, is below. Currently it will loop through all available rows and extract the department, but it always take the : and - with it! I can't seem to find a way to cut these out.

Any assistance?

I can probably work out the date bit eventually.

The final output from this code is ": Inbound Contacts -"
Where I need, "Inbound Contacts".

```
Sub stringSearch()
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim lastRow As Long, x As Long
    Dim matches As Variant, match As Variant
    Dim Reg_Exp As Object

    Set Reg_Exp = CreateObject("vbscript.regexp")

    Reg_Exp.Pattern = "\:\s(\w.+)\s\-"


    Set ws = Sheet2

    lastRow = ws.Range("C" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

    For x = 1 To lastRow
        Set matches = Reg_Exp.Execute(CStr(ws.Range("C" & x).Value))
        If matches.Count > 0 Then
            For Each match In matches
                ws.Range("B" & x).Value = match.Value
            Next match
        End If
    Next x
End Sub
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are not accessing Group 1 value.

Instead of `ws.Range("B" & x).Value = match.Value` use

```
ws.Range("B" & x).Value = match.Submatches(0)
```

You may also enhance the regex a bit to

```
Reg_Exp.Pattern = ":\s*(\w.*?)\s*-"
```

This way, you will "trim" the Group 1 value. See [**the regex demo**](https://regex101.com/r/5Y1lUZ/1).

**Details**

- `:` - a `:` char
- `\s*` - 0+ whitespace chars
- `(\w.*?)` - Group 1 (`.Submatches(0)`): a word char followed with any 0+ chars (other than line break chars) as few as possible (NOTE that `\w` does not match non-ASCII letters, probably you want to match any char that is not whitespace and not a `-`, then use `[^\s-]` instead of `\w`)
- `\s*` - 0+ whitespace chars
- `-` - a hyphen.

Comment: RegEx beginner here. Just curious what issues would `:\s*(.+)\s*?-` pattern will pose?

Comment: @shrivallabha.redij In that case, `\s*?` is redudnat, Group 1 value will always contain all the trailing whitespace chars it can find on its way to `-`.

Comment: Understood. Thank you!

Comment: Thank you! Worked perfectly. I knew it had something to do with calling the group. 
But I couldnt work out how in VBA!

Answer (score 4):

This is how to achieve what you want without [regex](/questions/tagged/regex), in general it should be a bit faster and way more understandable:

```
Sub TestMe()

    Dim inputString As String
    inputString = "Planning Unit: Inbound Contacts = Tuesday, 27/03/2018"
    Debug.Print Split(Split(inputString, ":")(1), "=")(0)

End Sub
```

- split the `inputString` by `:` and take the second part;
- split the taken part by `=` and take the first part;

Answer (score 1):

## Regex:

You can use this Regex: `([\s\S]+?):\s*([\s\S]+?)\s*-\s*([A-z]+)\s*,\s*([0-9]{2}\/[0-9]{2}\/[0-9]{4})\b`

And the [demo](https://regex101.com/r/K8SVRG/3)

## Code:

And this code:

```
Sub stringSearch()
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim lastRow As Long, x As Long
    Dim matches As Variant, match As Variant
    Dim Reg_Exp As Object

    Set Reg_Exp = CreateObject("vbscript.regexp")

    Reg_Exp.Pattern = "([\s\S]+?):\s*([\s\S]+?)\s*-\s*([A-z]+)\s*,\s*([0-9]{2}\/[0-9]{2}\/[0-9]{4})\b"


    Set ws = Sheet2

    lastRow = ws.Range("C" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

    For x = 1 To lastRow
        Set matches = Reg_Exp.Execute(CStr(ws.Range("C" & x).Value))
        If matches.Count > 0 Then
            For Each match In matches
                For i = 0 To match.SubMatches.Count - 1
                    Debug.Print match.SubMatches(i)
                Next i
            Next match
        End If
    Next x
End Sub
```

## Result

This is the result on the immediate window:

```
+-------------------+
| Planning Unit     |
| Inbound Contracts |
| Tuesday           |
| 27/03/2018        |
| Planning Unit     |
| Payments & Orders |
| Tuesday           |
| 27/03/2018        |
| Planning Unit     |
| Scheduling        |
| Tuesday           |
| 27/03/2018        |
+-------------------+
```

Answer (score 1):

I'd use Left/Right/Mid and InStr/InStrRev instead of RegEx in this case.

For extracting the department:

```
Dim mainStr As String
Dim deptStr As String
mainStr = "Planning Unit: Inbound Contacts - Tuesday, 27/03/2018"
deptStr = Mid(mainStr, InStr(mainStr, ":") + 2)
deptStr = Left(deptStr, InStr(deptStr, "-") - 2)
```

For extracting the date:

```
Dim mainStr As String
Dim dateStr As String
mainStr = "Planning Unit: Inbound Contacts - Tuesday, 27/03/2018"
dateStr = Right(mainStr, Len(mainStr) - InStrRev(mainStr, " "))
```

To be honest, this kind of situation is common enough that you might want to write some sort of "extractText" function to get the text between delimiters. Here's the one I use.

```
Function extractText(str As String, leftDelim As String, rightDelim As String, _
                     Optional reverseSearch As Boolean = False) As String
'Extracts text between two delimiters in a string
'By default, searches for first instance of each delimiter in string from left to right
'To search from right to left, set reverseSearch = True
'If left delimiter = "", function returns text up to right delimiter
'If right delimiter = "", function returns text after left delimiter
'If left or right delimiter not found in string, function returns empty string

    Dim leftPos As Long
    Dim rightPos As Long
    Dim leftLen As Long
    If reverseSearch Then
        leftPos = InStrRev(str, leftDelim)
        rightPos = InStrRev(str, rightDelim)
    Else
        leftPos = InStr(str, leftDelim)
        rightPos = InStr(str, rightDelim)
    End If

    leftPos = IIf(leftDelim = "", -1, leftPos)
    rightPos = IIf(rightDelim = "", -1, rightPos)
    leftLen = Len(leftDelim)

    If leftPos > 0 Then
        If rightPos = -1 Then
            extractText = Mid(str, leftPos + leftLen)
        ElseIf rightPos > leftPos Then
            extractText = Mid(str, leftPos + leftLen, rightPos - leftPos - leftLen)
        End If
    ElseIf leftPos = -1 Then
        If rightPos > 0 Then
            extractText = Left(str, rightPos - 1)
        End If
    End If

End Function
```